# count the number of yes and no for month & category in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I want help in re-displaying the data
( count the number of yes and no for month and category )  on Sheet 2 by code (automatically)

Example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14idoHEq1S__TJkpa07R86mCLhKx5i-FMcO5ZQZ8PWOo/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet1

[image]

To Sheet 2

[image]

Comment: It seems that you want to count the number of yes and no's for each month for each quarter, is that correct? If so, please write and describe that in your question

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote the answer below if you feel it was useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF('Sheet 1'!B2:F="",,
 MONTH('Sheet 1'!A2:A)&TEXT('Sheet 1'!A2:A, "mmmm")&"♦"&
 'Sheet 1'!B1:F1&"♦"&'Sheet 1'!B2:F&"♦"&'Sheet 1'!B2:F)), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col3)
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2
  pivot Col4
  label Col1'Month',Col2'ZONE' 
  format Col1'mmmm'"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the number of occurrence of a certain value and you know the range of cells, you could use `=COUNTIF(range, condition)` formula to your cells and to reference from different Sheet, use `=[SheetName]![cell]`.

Example:

**Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1]

To count the number of "Yes" in Sheet1, I used `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!B2:B9, "Yes")`.
**Sheet2**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to arrange months and Zone automatically?

Comment: Could you explain how the arrangement of Months and Zone should be?

Comment: Like the content of the Sheet 2

Comment: Do you mean to automatically populate Sheet2 or Sort Sheet2 using Month and Zone?